# How can I implement the PIMPL idiom in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, pimpl-idiom

I have a class that is implemented using the [PIMPL idiom](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/09/22/make-pimpl-using-unique_ptr/). A single instance of this class will be used across multiple threads within a multithreaded program. Inside the implementation of the class I made sure I did locking anywhere this class may read/write its own data, or use a shared resource.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Define the "Foo" class using the PIMPL idiom
class Foo final
{
public:
    Foo();

    ~Foo();

    void DoSomething(const int thread_num) const;

private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Define the implementation of "Foo"
struct Foo::Impl final
{
    void DoSomething(const int thread_num) const {

        // Lock before accessing the shared resource of "std::cout"
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        std::cout << "Doing something from thread " << thread_num << std::endl;
    }

private:
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Forward calls to the implementation
Foo::Foo()
    : m_impl(new Impl()) // Using C++11 so std::make_unique is not available
{}

Foo::~Foo() = default;

void Foo::DoSomething(const int thread_num) const
{
    // POSSIBLE LOCKING POINT A

    // Is dereferencing the "m_impl" pointer safe to do from multiple threads
    // without additional locking?
    m_impl->DoSomething(thread_num);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Use "Foo"
int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    // Is using "Foo" without locking safe here because it does a lock inside
    // DoSomething before using the shared resource "cout"?
    std::thread t1([&] {

        // POSSIBLE LOCKING POINT B

        foo.DoSomething(1);
    });

    std::thread t2([&] {

        // POSSIBLE LOCKING POINT B

        foo.DoSomething(2);
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

The question is... is this enough to be thread-safe? Do I also need to lock before dereferencing `m_impl` (POSSIBLE LOCKING POINT A), or is that well defined? To take it even further do I need to lock before even accessing `foo` at all between multiple threads (POSSIBLE LOCKING POINT B), or is that well defined?

My code seems to run consistently without issues the way it is locked above, but I just want to verify that I don't have any undefined behavior.

If the locking in the above example is not sufficient, then what is the correct way to lock in order to use a PIMPL class in a thread-safe manner?

Comment: if you don't modify it it's fine. (as in this case)

Comment: actually the `m_mutex` only guard against `cout` here, the class itself do not need it.

Comment: Private `mutable` mutex with lock hidden in every method is probably the worst way to achieve thread safety. Note `::std::cout` itself is already thread safe so if you want to write into it from multiple threads then it would be a good idea to write the whole message into local buffer (`stringstream`) and then submit its entire content to `cout` as a single operation without any synchronization. With c++20 there is a dedicated class available just for this purpose `std::osyncstream`.

Comment: `cout` is threadsafe in the sense that it's not undefined behavior to access it from multiple threads without synchronization, but this code _does_ provide a stronger guarantee that for example messages "Doing something from thread 1" and "Doing something from thread 2" won't get interwoven in the output as "Doing something from thread Doing something from thread 2 1"

Comment: @NathanPierson okay, but consider if `DoSomething` modified a member variable of `Foo::Impl`, would this code still be "thread-safe" then? I'm just trying to figure out where locking is *actually* necessary. Can the locking all be encapsulated in the class, or do I need to lock outside of the class in the threads themselves? Also is accessing the `m_impl` pointer itself from multiple threads safe if I modify a member variable of `Foo::Impl` with a lock in the function it is calling?

Comment: @user7860670 then what is the proper way to achieve thread safety (assuming I was using something other than `std::cout` in `DoSomething` that is not on its own thread-safe... For example if `DoSomething` modified a member variable of `Foo::Impl`). That's what I was trying to depict with my example.

Comment: If you are going to use member mutex then it would be a good idea to avoid `mutable` qualifier (and make methods using it not const-qualified) for the sake of clarity. If this class is supposed to have many methods then i suggest to create auxiliary "access" class that will incapsulate mutex lock and act as a proxy when invoking those methods. So several consecutive method calls would require only a single lock/unlock sequence rather than one per method invocation.

Comment: It's OK to access and dereference `m_impl` without synchronization. Only constructor and destructor modify this member, and those never run concurrently with other methods (in a program free of undefined behavior).